# atom-typescript can not find typings

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I just configured a new Angular/Typescript project in Atom using atom-typescript. The project is set up to have a main angular module file that imports all of the modules, including the type definition files. Everything compiles in gulp and runs no problem.

Since I'm using gulp, I've configured atom-typescript to not compile the .ts files on save. Now, I'm seeing errors in all of my .ts files showing that the atom-typescript linter cannot find the typings.

Ex: `Module 'ng' has no exported member 'IScope' at line 1 col 32`

I know that I can probably solve this problem by adding a reference path to each of my ts files like `/// <reference path="../../.tmp/typings/tsd.d.ts" />`, but that seems really redundant and unnecessary.

Since these errors are being raised by atom-typescript, is there any way that I can set the location of my type definition files somewhere in the settings for the whole project? Any other suggestions for how to handle this?

Comment: Put the typings in the `tsconfig.json` file along with the other `ts` files. Since you are using atom-typescript, you can even use glob patterns

Comment: Awesome, that pointed me in the right direction towards the atom-typescript files glob (https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md#filesglob). All I had to do was add a glob for the typings and one for the rest of the .ts files for good measure. @BrunoGrieder if you post an answer with that info I'll add that as the accepted response.

Comment: Glad it helped. Posted as answer below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the typings in the `tsconfig.json` file along with the other ts files in the `files` entry.

Since you are using atom-typescript, you can even use [glob patterns](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md#filesglob), i.e.

```
{
...
    "filesGlob": [
        "./typescript/**/*.ts",
        "./typescript/**/*.tsx",
        "./typings/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
...
}
```

The `files` entry will be automatically updated.

**Edit**

Since this is now officially supported by Typescript, a more portable solution (across IDEs) may be to use the `exclude` property of `tsconfig`.

This works the other other way round: compile everything *but* what is excluded (typically anything under `node_modules` and the static assets in, says, `public`)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "public"
    ]
}
```

Official details at this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json)

Comment: This was the craziest thing I've ever seen Atom do. You're awesome Bruno.