# Typescript, declaration and CommonJS

Tags: typescript

I'm confused when creating declaration files (d.ts).

For example, I created a NPM package "a" (one CommonJS module index.ts):

```
export interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

export default function sub(one: IPoint, two: IPoint): IPoint {
    return {
        x: one.x - two.x,
        y: one.y - two.y
    };    
}
```

Compile it and generate a.d.ts:

```
export interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
export default function sub(one: IPoint, two: IPoint): IPoint;
```

As I understand the compiler can not generate valid d.ts for CommonJS. 
Must use utilities as dts-generator or to wrap manually:

```
declare module "a" 
{
    export interface IPoint {
        x: number;
        y: number;
    }
    export default function sub(one: IPoint, two: IPoint): IPoint;
}
```

Ok. Now I am doing the package "b" (which depends on "a"):

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/a/a.d.ts" />

import sub from "a"
import { IPoint } from "a"
export { IPoint }

export default function distance(one: IPoint, two: IPoint): number {
    var s = sub(one, two);
    return Math.sqrt(s.x * s.x + s.y * s.y);
}
```

Ok, it work. Now a want a package "c" that depends on "b" (and so on).

1. How to specify the dependence in the module "b" (link to "a.d.ts")?
   Trying to specify in "node_modules"?
   Or copy "a.d.ts" to "/typings/" directory in the "b" package?
   And then copy "a.d.ts" and "b.d.ts" to "/typings/" in the "c" package (and so on)?
2. What is the point from sections "typings" in "package.json"?
   I write in "b/package.json":

   "typings": "./b.d.ts"

And get the error when compiling "c":

```
Exported external package typings file 'node_modules/b/b.d.ts' is not a module.
```

3. How to create d.ts files for CommonJS module?
   So that do not write manually "declare module", "reference" and etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As I understand the compiler can not generate valid d.ts for CommonJS. Must use utilities as dts-generator or to wrap manually:

Actually no (since 1.6).

Simply compile module `a` passing the `declaration` flag to `tsc`.
The transpiler will generate the declaration files for you.

You are right that these files are not external definition file, but internal definition files

**however**

Module `b` will be able to *automatically* find and use these files if, in the `package.json` of module a, the `typings` entry points to the generated `index.d.ts` file

### To recap:

Module a:

- compîle with the `declaration` flag
- update the `typings` entry to point to the generated `.d.ts` file

Module b:

- simply `import * as moduleA from 'a'` or `import {IPoint} from module 'a'`

No clumsy `///<reference=` or hand-made typings

Comment: Oh, so simple :)

Thank you, Bruno!

But, if the library contains many modules?
As "lodash" for example.

I can include the particular module:

`let toArray = require("lodash/lang/toArray");`

How to specify d.ts for nested modules?

I received the following:

- I have index.ts and submodule.ts
- Compiled and created index.d.ts and submodule.d.ts
- It working! :)
- But I cannot move d.ts files to separate directory from the root.
- I write 'typings: "./typings/my-module.d.ts"' and it working for the main module, but nested doesn't resolve.

It can be fixed?

Comment: Long comment ;) For "pure" js libraries, get the definition/typings from [definitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) and reference them in the `files` section of `tsconfig.json`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271914/atom-typescript-can-not-find-typings/34281587#34281587).