# Having a .d.ts for nodejs dependencies and one for front dependencies?

Tags: typescript

It's possible to have a `.d.ts` with all nodejs dependencies (like express, body-parser, etc) and an other .d.ts for front dependencies (like angular, jquery, etc) generated by tsd?

Or should i have to create my own .d.ts manually outside typings folder that refers others .d.ts?

Comment: You can concatenate d.ts files, but.... why would you do that in the first place ?

Comment: In my project i have TS source for the backend (nodejs) and the frontend (angular).
The tsd.d.ts contains all dependencies and i want to separate front and back dependencies for the _/// <reference path="path/to/files.d.ts" />_ for my .ts files.

Comment: Do not use `///<reference path= ...` pragmas. Just reference all `.d.ts` files in the `files` entry of your `tsconfig.json` and forget about them.

Answer (score 1):

As general rules

1. Do not write `d.ts` files manually; It is hard  and there are many pitfalls associated with them. The only reason you may have to do this is because a "pure" js library does not have typings on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)
2. Do not use `///<reference path=...>` pragmas. Since 1.6, simply reference your d.ts files in the `files` entry of `tsconfig.json` and forget about them. Some plugins like `grunt-ts` or the `atom-typescript-plugin` will even maintain the list for you (same developer).
3. Separate front-end and back-end code in two projects. If there is code which is shared between the two, create a library that is imported in both project. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272128/typescript-declaration-and-commonjs/34272618#34272618) for a brief introduction on how to do it.